# How to create list in sql based on condition

Tags: sql, data-structures, google-bigquery, apache-spark-sql, azure-sql-database

I am working on a SQL query, where considering the following dataset:

| clientid | visited | channel | purchase | visit_order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | abc133 | google | 0 | 1 |
| 123 | efg446 | facebook | 0 | 2 |
| 123 | gij729 | instagram | 1 | 3 |
| 456 | klm183 | google | 0 | 1 |
| 456 | nop496 | linkedin | 0 | 2 |
| 456 | qrs729 | pinterest | 1 | 3 |
| 456 | tuv894 | google | 0 | 1 |
| 456 | wyz634 | instagram | 0 | 2 |

I want to get the following output:

| clientid | user_journey | conversion |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | google, facebook, instagram | 1 |
| 456 | google, linkedin, interest | 1 |
| 456 | google, instagram | 0 |

where the **user_jorney** column is composed of the channels that participated in a conversion journey. Note that the journey of users who, until then, have not made a purchase is also built.

Looking for commands that can help with this task, I found concat_ws, where I wrote the code below:

```
select 
  clientid, 
  concat_ws(',', collect_list(channel)) as user_journey, 
  sum(purchase) as conversion
from table_name group by  clientid;
```

I get this result:

| clientid | user_journey | conversion |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | google, facebook, instagram | 1 |
| 456 | google, linkedin, pinterest, google, instagram | 1 |

Now I'm trying to consider a condition to get the desired result but so far I haven't been able to find.

Could you help me how can i solve this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: you are missing very important data point that most likely available in your data - which is timestamp or data or something that allows determine global order of visits
Having this in mind consider below (`ts` is reference to the missing in your question column)

```
select clientid, 
  string_agg(channel, ', ' order by visit_order) user_journey,
  sum(purchase) as conversion
from (
  select *, countif(visit_order = 1) over(partition by clientid order by ts) grp
  from your_table
)
group by clientid, grp
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]